# How to get logs into the Tool Log in Release Management for Visual Studio

Tags: ms-release-management, vstest

In the Release Management for Visual Studio Deployment log, which can be found under the Details button found when viewing the details of a release, there are a number of columns.

The last three of these are Tool Log, Command Output and Status.

I have never seen anything in Tool Log, but I am in the situation now where I have a component running tests using vstest.console.exe.

Under "Command Output", I see the output from this program as it appears in the console window. However, vstest.console.exe can also be instructed to create a test log (a .trx file), which I would like to view under Tool Log. But I have no idea how to make this happen.

How do I get a log to appear under the Tool Log column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is to set the "Log File Name" in the Tool definition to whatever log file you wish to view (in my case, the .trx file).

This obviously requires that you are using a tool that defines this, or a custom one. Fortunately, I'm using a custom tool.

Comment: I know it seems I answered this quickly, but honestly, I've been looking for this for days.

Answer (score 1):

Your Tool have to copy/create the .trx file to/in the Tool's work directory (%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\RM\T\RM\\).

Don't forget to add .trx extesion to Administration -> Settings -> Approved File Extension List.