# Opening test result from Release Management

Tags: testing, tfs, trx

Our build through RM executes tests and produces a result file (*.TRX extension).  It had been added to the approved list in RM.  However, when I clicked on the link "View Log" in the Deployment Log, it threw this error :"an error occurred while sending command to the application".  How can I get it opened directly in Visual Studio?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the last action is failed, you need to check whether your tool has copy/create the .trx file to/in the Tool's work directory.

This case may be also helpful: [How to get logs into the Tool Log in Release Management for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561081/how-to-get-logs-into-the-tool-log-in-release-management-for-visual-studio)